# Tracing NSzombie and nsexception with arc and xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

In my application i have a slide btn to switch between the two view which have a parent view .. Hierarchy is like this

Detail(Parent)
-A(Subview of detail)
-B(Subview of detail)

Detail is main view and A and B are sub-view
Every time user click on Btn the view is being switched.. View A and B have map view and some heavy calculation to show the map point annotations.
So when its calculating the annotation for display I am using MBProgressHud to display the progress indicator. But after switching the view from A to B its crashing. I enabled the nszombie and its giving the following error

- Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class ‘_NSZombie_NSException’
  libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Its showing no specific line where the code is crashing . Please help me how to find out the nszombie 
I am using xcode 4.5 with arc and application is for ios 6.

If you want code snippet i can post.

Answer (score 5):

Please select in XCode the breakpoints tab in the leftmost navigator area. Tap on the plus sign left bottom. In the context menu select "Add exception breakpoint". In the new context menu, simply click "done". This will enable a breakpoint for all exceptions.
So when you run your app, the program execution will stop at the instruction that raises the exception. Most likely, you are accessing an object there, that has already been released.
If you don't use ARC yet, maybe you should consider it. It eliminates most of memory management problems.